# Flag when character appears more than once in a string

Tags: r, string, grepl

I have seen something similar answered for Python but not for R. Say I have the sample data below, and I want to create the "want" column, which flags when the character "|" appears more than once in the string in the "var1" column. How would I do this in R? I know I can use `grepl` to flag whenever "|" appears, but this would also capture when it only appears once.

Sample data:

```
var1<-c("BLUE|RED","RED|BLUE","WHITE|BLACK|ORANGE","BLACK|WHITE|ORANGE")
want<-c(0,0,1,1)
have<-as.data.frame(cbind(var1,want))


var1                 want
BLUE|RED              0
RED|BLUE              0
WHITE|BLACK|ORANGE    1
BLACK|WHITE|ORANGE    1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str_count` can be used - count the number of `|` (metacharacter - so escape (`\\`) or specify as `fixed`, and then create a logical vector (`> 1`), convert the logical to binary (`as.integer` or `+`)

```
library(stringr)
have$want <- +(str_count(have$var1, fixed("|") ) > 1)
```